# jPlayer duration and progress error

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, mobile, jplayer

I have a few jPlayer instances, obviously with diferent id.

**Edit**: Here is my current Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/UrielUVD/8t52eqsp/

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
  ready: function () {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
      title: "test",
      mp3: "sourceofmp3"
  });
  },
  timeupdate: function(event) {
      $("#jp-progress-slider-1").slider("value",event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute);
    },
  swfPath: "jquery.jplayer.swf",
  cssSelectorAncestor: '#jp_container_1',
  cssSelector:
  {
  play: '.icon-play1',
  pause: '.icon-pause1',
  seekBar: '.ui-slider',
  playBar: '.ui-slider-range',
  currentTime: '.jp-current-time',
  duration: '.jp-duration'
  },
  supplied: "mp3",
  solution_play: "flash, html",
  wmode: "window",
  mobile:true,
  preload: "metadata",
  volume: 1,
  duration:true,
  keyEnabled: true,
  errorAlerts: true
});
```

And his respective jquery ui slider

```
$("#jp-progress-slider-1").slider({
animate: "fast",
max: 100,
range: "min",
step: 0.1,
value : 0,
slide: function(event, ui) {
  var sp = $("#jquery_jplayer_1").data("jPlayer").status.seekPercent;

  if(sp > 0) {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("playHead", ui.value * (100 / sp));
  } else {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $( "#jp-progress-slider-1").slider("value", 0);
    }, 0);
  }
 }
});
```

In web everything works fine, duration, current time, current progress, events and listeners...

But in mobile (adnroid) duration,currentPercentAbsolute,currentPercentRelative are always 0
The player plays,pauses and stops normally but this values of the status are always 0
What´s wrong?

**Edit 1:** So far, this error is only shown in Android Chrome 39, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At last!**

I foud what was wrong...

- No error in JavaScript code
- No error in URL sources
- No error in audio mime types
- No error in JQuery-ui, Jplayer or JPlayer.swf

The error was in the server!!!
It has enable **gzip compression**

I used **SetEnv no-gzip 1** in the .htaccess to solve it

> Do Not GZIP the Media
>
> Disable GZIP encoding of all the media files. Media files are already >compressed and the GZIP will just waste CPU on your server.
>
> The Adobe Flash Plugin will experience issues if you GZIP the media.
>
> Do not GZIP the Jplayer.swf file either. Feel free to GZIP the JavaScript

http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/

This is the only reference to the possible bug that i found so far

**NOTE: So far this bug is only shown in Android Chorme 
 If you're experimenting some issues of the list below in mobile browsers give it a try**

- Audio playing but, not metadata loaded
- Can't set url despite the url is right and accessible
- Can't trigger the timeupdate event even when the audio is playing